# In what order does a bash FOR IN loop pick up files in a folder?

Tags: shell, wildcards, for

Say I have a below for in loop:

```
for i in /apps/textfiles/*.txt
do
do something
done
```

Now say I have 50 files inside **/apps/textfiles/**

In what order will the files be picked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Filename expansion in Bash is sorting **alphabetically**.

[From the Bash Manual:](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion)

> Bash scans each word for the characters ‘`*`’, ‘`?`’, and ‘`[`’. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern [...].

It doesn't make a difference here that your globbing context is part of the `for` loop.

Note that *alphabetical* sorting still obeys the collation order defined by the [`LC_COLLATE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-LC_005fCOLLATE) variable:

> `LC_COLLATE`
>
> This variable determines the collation order used when sorting the results of filename expansion, and determines the behavior of range expressions, equivalence classes, and collating sequences within filename expansion and pattern matching (see Filename Expansion).

Comment: And by alphabetically, they mean according to the order defined by your locale `LC_COLLATE`.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=C` is ASCIIbetical, it's instructive to experiment with something like this `seq 32 127|awk '{printf("%c\n",$1)}' | LC_COLLATE=en_US sort`